# Error when invoking a method through .NET COM interop

Tags: c#, com-interop

I am trying to use the [IOfficeAntiVirus COM interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff830310.aspx) to invoke a scan using the Microsoft security essentials virus scanner.

I am doing early binding because the documentation says that IOfficeAntiVirus interface inherits from IUknown and does not support IDispatch.

```
[Guid("56FFCC30-D398-11d0-B2AE-00A0C908FA49"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)
]
public interface IOfficeAntiVirus
{
    void Scan(IntPtr info);
}

[ComImport, Guid("2781761E-28E1-4109-99FE-B9D127C57AFE")]
class SecurityEssentialsAntiVirus
{
}
```

The parameter for the scan method is a type that comes from [this example](http://www.enhanceie.com/ie/IOfficeAntiVirusInCSharp.asp). That example does the opposite of what I want because it implements the IOfficeAntiVirus interface using a .NET class rather than invoking the scan method. The marshalling and types in the example seem to [match the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff830314.aspx) as far as I can tell.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct MSOAVINFO
{
public int cbsize;

[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
public uint uFlags;
public IntPtr hwnd;

[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
public string pwzFullPath;

[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
public string pwzHostname;

[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
public string pwzOrigURL;
}
```

This is the code I'm trying to use to invoke the scan method:

```
var antivirus = (IOfficeAntiVirus)new SecurityEssentialsAntiVirus();
var file = new MSOAVINFO();
file.pwzFullPath = @"test.txt";
IntPtr lParam = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(file));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(file, lParam, false);
antivirus.Scan(lParam);
```

It fails on the call to the scan method. I get an exception that says:

> "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt."

I'm running this from a 32 bit command line app on a 64 bit system. I have experimented with running the command line program in both 32 bit and 64 bit with no success.

I am sure that the IOfficeAntiVirus guid is correct because I got it from the documentation. Also trying a random GUID that isn't a COM interface causes an error when I try to cast the object to the interface.

I am sure that the SecurityEssentialsAntiVirus guid implements the IOfficeAntiVirus because when I tried casting a different type of COM object to that interface I got an error.

I think the problem might be that the Scan method on the interface hasn't been correctly declared (declaring a random method on the interface gives the same error). I am not working from documentation for the security essentials assembly so it might not implement the interface in the way I imagine (or at all). Does anyone have any idea how to check that?

I can see a MpOAv.dll file in its directory and that is the same name as the header file in the IOfficeAntiVirus documentation, I know that's not a lot to go on. I can't open that dll up in ole-com object viewer to see what is inside. I get a message saying:

> IMoniker::BindToObject failed on the file moniker created from (
>   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Security Client\MpOAv.dll" ). Bad
>   extension for file
>
> MK_E_INVALIDEXTENSION ($800401E6)

It also could be that I'm not passing the struct correctly to the Scan method. I have tried about a hundred variations without any luck including using AllocCoTaskMem() and passing the struct by reference.

I'm really not had much experience doing interop (learnt a heap today trying to figure this out!) so I'd really appreciate a push in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm was also spent a couple of days on the same problem but without any results. The maximum what I was able to do it run check without any errors but even for malware it returns OK status, in my case

So, I continued research and found that [Mozilla](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla1.9.2/source/toolkit/components/downloads/src/nsDownloadScanner.cpp) uses [IAttachmentExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776297.aspx) antivirus API for checks. And Save method, of it, doing same job like 
Scan of IOfficeAntiVirus

> IAttachmentExecute::Save may run virus scanners or other trust
>   services to validate the file before saving it. Note that these
>   services can delete or alter the file.

and implementation of it on codeples http://antivirusscanner.codeplex.com/

Comment: So glad you figured it out! There's five days of my life I'm never getting back. :)

Answer (score 0):

One thing I notice is that you didn't set cbsize. file.cbsize=Marshal.SizeOf(file);

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that but it did make a difference.